# In React, When I close the modal, I cannot scroll down/up

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-functional-component

I am just getting started learning React with Function Component and Styled-Components. I created Modal Component and when I clicked the modal it shows up and I cannot scroll down/up(Background) but when I close the modal, I cannot scroll. I expect it should be work when I close the modal. Could you help me with what part something wrong?

```
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

  const openModal = active => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev);
    if (active) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }
  };
```

```
<ShowAllSizes>
  <AllSize>모든 사이즈</AllSize>
  <FaRegArrowAltCircleDown // isActive={active} onClick={()=> openModal}
    className="FaIconModal"
    />

    <Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
</ShowAllSizes>
```

I will leave the whole code just in case

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { FaRegArrowAltCircleDown } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Modal } from './components/Modal';

export default function ColumnTop() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

  const openModal = active => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev);
    if (active) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }
  };
  return (
    <RightSideSection>
      <ColumnTopSection>
        <TitleBox>
          <BrandName>Jordan</BrandName>
          <EngName>Jordan 1 Retro High OG Bordeaux</EngName>
          <KrName>조던 1 레트로 하이 OG 보르도</KrName>
        </TitleBox>
        <FigureWrap>
          <DetailSize>
            <SizeInKorean>사이즈</SizeInKorean>
            <ShowAllSizes>
              <AllSize>모든 사이즈</AllSize>
              <FaRegArrowAltCircleDown
                // isActive={active}
                onClick={() => openModal}
                className="FaIconModal"
              />

              <Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
            </ShowAllSizes>
          </DetailSize>
          <DetailPrice>
            <TransactionPriceKorean>최근 거래가</TransactionPriceKorean>
            <PriceInfo>
              <CurrentPrice>248,000</CurrentPrice>
              <PricePunctuation>6000원(-2.4%)</PricePunctuation>
            </PriceInfo>
          </DetailPrice>
          <ButtonWrapper>
            <Button>
              <ButtonDivision>
                <LeftSide>
                  <BtnTitle to="/order">구매</BtnTitle>
                </LeftSide>
                <RightSide>
                  <OrderPrice>23500원</OrderPrice>
                  <OrderStatusName>즉시 구매가</OrderStatusName>
                </RightSide>
              </ButtonDivision>
            </Button>

            <Button primary>
              <ButtonDivision>
                <LeftSide>
                  <BtnTitle to="/order">판매</BtnTitle>
                </LeftSide>
                <RightSide>
                  <OrderPrice>11500원</OrderPrice>
                  <OrderStatusName>즉시 판매가</OrderStatusName>
                </RightSide>
              </ButtonDivision>
            </Button>
          </ButtonWrapper>
        </FigureWrap>
      </ColumnTopSection>
    </RightSideSection>
  );
}
const ShowAllSizes = styled.div``;
const RightSideSection = styled.div`
  padding-left: 40px;
`;

const ColumnTopSection = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const TitleBox = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const BrandName = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 19px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
  width: 61px;
  height: 21px;
`;

const EngName = styled.span`
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
`;

const KrName = styled.span`
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
`;
const FigureWrap = styled.div`
  width: 500px;
`;
const DetailSize = styled.div`
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
`;
const SizeInKorean = styled.span`
  padding-top: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
`;
const AllSize = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 392px;
  font-size: 18px;
`;

const FaIconModal = styled.button``;

const DetailPrice = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 4px;
`;

const TransactionPriceKorean = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  height: 7px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
`;

const PriceInfo = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 330px;
`;

const CurrentPrice = styled.span`
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 4px;
`;
const PricePunctuation = styled.span`
  color: #31b46e;
  margin-left: 110px;
`;

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-top: 15px;
`;

const ButtonDivision = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  background: ${props => (props.primary ? '#41B979' : '#EF6253')};

  width: 235px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
`;

const LeftSide = styled.div`
  margin-top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
`;
const BtnTitle = styled(Link)`
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
`;

const RightSide = styled.div`
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
  color: #fff;
`;

const OrderPrice = styled.div`
  margin-left: 10px;
`;
const OrderStatusName = styled.div`
  margin-left: 20px;
`;
```

This is my Modal Component

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { MdClose } from 'react-icons/md';

export const Modal = ({ showModal, setShowModal }) => {
  const modalRef = useRef();
  const [detailPageData, setDetailPageData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/data/detailPageData.json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setDetailPageData(data.result.price_by_size));
  }, []);

  const closeModal = e => {
    if (modalRef.current === e.target) {
      setShowModal(false);
    }
  };

  const keyPress = useCallback(
    e => {
      if (e.key === 'Escape' && showModal) {
        setShowModal(false);
      }
    },
    [setShowModal, showModal]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
  }, [keyPress]);
  // console.log(setDetailPageData);
  return (
    <div>
      {showModal ? (
        <Background onClick={closeModal} ref={modalRef}>
          <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
            <SizeModalContent>
              <Title>사이즈</Title>
              <ButtonWrapper>
                {detailPageData.map(({ id, title, price }) => {
                  return (
                    <Button key={id}>
                      <Size>{title}</Size>
                      <Price>{price}</Price>
                    </Button>
                  );
                })}
              </ButtonWrapper>
            </SizeModalContent>

            <CloseModalButton
              aria-label="Close modal"
              onClick={() => setShowModal(prev => !prev)}
            />
          </ModalWrapper>
        </Background>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

const Background = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -0px;
  top: -0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 10;
`;

const ModalWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;

  border-radius: 10px;
`;

const SizeModalContent = styled.div`
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
`;
const Title = styled.div`
  margin: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
`;

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 10px 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;

  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
`;

const Size = styled.span`
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700px;
`;

const Price = styled.span`
  color: red;
`;

const CloseModalButton = styled(MdClose)`
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  right: 800px;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* top: -50px;
  right: -360px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px; */
`;
```

Edit1: Copy and Past my Modal.js

Comment: Can you also share the `Modal` component code? If possible could you try also to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your adivse! I just added Modal.js file and I will check codesandbox! I've never used it but I will check right now how do I use it

Comment: If you are familiar with VSCode it will feel like second nature... otherwise it is a very simple to use web IDE.

Comment: what controls isActive ?

Comment: setIsActive(false) in closeModal();
and setIsActive(true) in openModal();